# How do mining pools ensure pool members don't cheat?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-reward, mining-pool-shares

If I understand well, when being part of a pool, you are asking to solve problems that are easier than the real one, typically finding a hash starting with n zeros instead of n+1 or something.
And you will be awarded some fraction of BTC depending on how much "easy" problems you solved.

But when (if) you find by chance a solution to the full difficult problem, why would you send it to the pool and not submitting a block to the network by yourself and not sharing anything?

Comment: You understand everything correctly. That's why Bitmain/AntMiner hesitate to release even GPL components of their miners, so that people don't modify code that submits every piece of work.

Comment: That is not true at all.

Comment: What difference do you think it makes who submits the block? It's the same block regardless of who submits it.

Comment: The question was successfully answered, I didn't think about the fact that the fool could pre-register its wallet when sending work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The work given by a pool includes the coinbase transaction which defines the payment as going to the pool, and is unique to that. If the client modifies the payout address, the proof of work they have done is invalidated. They can not steal money from the pool by doing this.